# How to select the second most frequent value in column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you please help me with this select query?

[countries table in DB AS photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDBAJ.png)

I need to select the most second frequent (duplicated) country in the column

Output should be like this:
IT

Comment: can you provide your coding attempt at this problem? It may require a small tweak to make it working @SafohSassa

Comment: what do you want if there are ties for first or second place?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be shorter and simpler queries, but this one should work on every DB and prevent issues like the key words `LIMIT`, `TOP` etc. can't be used on all different DB's.

```
SELECT name FROM Countries
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = (SELECT MAX(a.amount) AS amount
FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS amount
FROM Countries
GROUP BY name) a
WHERE amount < (SELECT MAX(b.amount) FROM
(SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS amount
FROM Countries
GROUP BY name)b));
```

This query will find step by step the second frequent value of your table using sub queries.

Comment: Your answer is the best, your query show every country which is the second most duplicated . Perfect , thank you 

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM Countries
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY count(name) DESC
LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: Thank you but it shows error

Comment: @SafohSassa - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Mt4F4CkzV8ExBdCk2YTfU/0

Comment: Thank you very much:) i checked it in mysql and got error , is it for sql or mysql ?

Comment: This is no correct answer. Have a look to your fiddle again, add one more row with name "US" and execute the query again. You will see the outcome of your query is still US, but now the second frequent value is no longer "US", but both "UK" and "CZ".

Comment: @SafohSassa: When looking at the DB-FIDDLE it's pretty clear that this attempt was done on a MySQL5.7 database  (see: top left of the screen after opening the link)

Comment: @RajatGoel: see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Mt4F4CkzV8ExBdCk2YTfU/0

Comment: @Rajat Goel
your queries works  but if there are for example two countries are the second most duplicated , your query shows only one of them 

https://recordit.co/hEwNpLFPSr

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use this also

```
with flo as (
select country , count(*)as cate, dense_rank()over( order by count(*)  desc)as rnk
from yourtable
group by country)
select country from flo 
where rnk=2
```

Comment: it shows error

https://recordit.co/yyktcyrPna

Comment: @Safoh Sassa
 check your code pls because with your data from the photo  and my solution  it give the correct result -it

Answer (score 0):

i wrote now this query and it worked well too :)

```
SELECT name FROM Countries GROUP BY name HAVING count(name) = (
SELECT a.amount from (
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(name) as amount FROM countries GROUP BY name ORDER 
by amount DESC limit 1,1) a  )
```